# To delete all folders in the current directory with pattern matching

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to delete all the folders in current directory that starts with say "foo" followed by date
for example we have

1. foo20120620
2. foo20120513
3. fooblabla

I can successfully delete one folder that matches current date
 example

```
set FOO_FOLDER=%CD%\foo%datetimef%      

echo Y | rd /s/q %FOO_FOLDER%
```

But I'm not able to delete all the folders starting with foo.

I have been tried something like

```
set OLD_PATTERN="%CD%\foo"     
del %OLD_PATTERN%*
```

I have googled and tried to follow some questions already being asked in this forum , but those doesn't help me a lot.

Any  suggestion will be  of great  help to me.
must be in batch scripting on windows side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `FOR /D` command.

```
for /d %%p in (foo*) do rd /s /q "%%p"
```

Comment: You missed the `IN` just before the brackets

Comment: I am sorry , in a hurry , i typed wrong command in my batch file .. I guess ur comment is working . I will let you know in few minutes

Comment: Hi Guys, there is minute problem. when I try to execute the above command it ask user permission to delete it . I have append "echo Y | " before the command and it still ask for user confirmation. can we do  something about that?

Answer (score 1):

The magical [for command in dos batch](http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm)....

from the command line

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir .\foo* /ad/b') do rd "%f" /s/q
```

from the batch file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir .\foo* /ad/b') do rd "%%f" /s/q
```

/f runs the command in the '' in the brackets, and tokenises its. By saying tokens=* all the file/dir name goe into one variable %f

here is an example

```
C:\temp>md foo3

C:\temp>md foo2

C:\temp>md foo1

C:\temp>dir
 Volume in drive C is TEST
 Volume Serial Number is F47F-AAE1

 Directory of C:\temp

18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          .
18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          ..
18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          foo1
18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          foo2
18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          foo3
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  131,009,933,312 bytes free

C:\temp>for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir .\foo* /ad/b') do rd "%f" /s/q

C:\temp>rd "foo1" /s/q

C:\temp>rd "foo2" /s/q

C:\temp>rd "foo3" /s/q

C:\temp>dir /ad
 Volume in drive C is TEST
 Volume Serial Number is F47F-AAE1

 Directory of C:\temp

18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          .
18/06/2012  09:42 p.m.    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  131,009,933,312 bytes free

C:\temp>
```

Comment: (a) No need to use `for /f`. (b) This will mangle Unicode folder names under default settings. (c) The syntax is wrong and doesn't even work.

Comment: @Preet, Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. it definitely helps me . Though I have used Jeb command , but I must thank you for the interest you have shown . cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I thought it would be worth mentioning that the FOR command creates parameter variables which are identified with a letter rather than a number (e.g. %%G), so, in order to avoid confusion between parameters and pathname format letters, avoid using the letters (a, d, f, n, p, s, t, x, z) as FOR parameters or just choose a FOR parameter letter that is UPPER case.

Format letters are case sensitive, so using a capital letter is also a good way to avoid conflicts, eg. %%A rather than %%a.

[Reference](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)