# delete windows folder using pattern matching

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, matching

I want to delete folders within a folder by identifying the folders with specific patter that I'm looking for. ..for example if there are 6 folder as below, i want to delete folders with pattern that has string "-dated" as part of folder name ... can some one help me how I can do this in a batch file

```
1 . "target-dated-29sep"
2 . "target-dated-28sep"
3 . "target"
4 . "target-dated-27sep"*
5 . "BIN"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [To delete all folders in the current directory with pattern matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080041/to-delete-all-folders-in-the-current-directory-with-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]` with a pattern in the set part of the command like so:

```
FOR /d %%a in (\*dated\*) DO RD /s /q "%%a"
```

NOTES:

- The `%` needs to be escaped inside the batch file, whereas directly in the command line you would only need a single `%` sign.
- This assumes you are running the batch script directly from the same path as the folders.
- For more information check the command line help: `for /?` and `rd /?`