# Dos command to delete specific directories

Tags: dos, del

cd to myFolder
I want to delete from myFolder all folders starting with tmp

how could I do it in dos command ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080041/to-delete-all-folders-in-the-current-directory-with-pattern-matching

Comment: this doesn't answer my question ... even if I try cmd gievn in asnwer of link you gave %%p not work with dos command window

Comment: use one percent instead of two if you're running from a command window, as shown in the second answer in that link

Answer (score 1):

rmtemp.bat:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /B /O /AD temp*') DO rmdir %%G
```

works only if stored in a .bat but not if entered manually in cmd line.